# Uncaught ReferenceError: Isotope is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-isotope

I'm attempting to integrate the Isotope library into my custom WordPress theme to achieve filtering and sorting functionality. However, I'm encountering an error in the console: "Isotope is not defined." I've followed the steps to enqueue Isotope and jQuery, and I'm not sure what's causing this issue. here is my functions.php file code

```
function amco_enqueue_assets()
{
    // Enqueue your stylesheets
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/all.min.css', [], '6.4.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', [], '5.2.3', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('custome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', [], filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/css/style.css'), 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('main-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), [], '1.0.0');
    // Enqueue your scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', [], '3.6.1');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', ['jquery'], '5.2.3');
    wp_enqueue_script('isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/isotope.pkgd.js', ['jquery'], '5.2.3', true);
    // //eqnueue filter js
    wp_register_script('main-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js',  [], filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/js/main.js'));
    wp_enqueue_script('lightbox-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.bundle.min.js', ['jquery'], '1.8.3');
    // Enqueue the registered script
    wp_enqueue_script('main-script', true);
}


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'amco_enqueue_assets');
```

here is my main.js file

```
  var gridElement = document.querySelector('#trade-list');
  var grid = new Isotope(gridElement, {
    transitionDuration: "0.5s",
  });
  
  // Filter items on button click
  var filterButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".filter-button-group button");
  
  filterButtons.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
      var filterValue = this.getAttribute("data-filter");
      grid.arrange({ filter: filterValue });
    });
  });
```

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script('isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/isotope.pkgd.js', ['jquery'], '5.2.3', true);` that last argument, `true`, is the 5th argument. Documentation here, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/. 5th argument is $args. `An array of additional script loading strategies.
Otherwise, it may be a boolean in which case it determines whether the script is printed in the footer. Default false.` Your isotope script is being loaded at the bottom of the page. It needs to be loaded BEFORE you use it in another script. That's probably your proble

Comment: Figure out what script you're using it in, and make sure isotope is loaded before that script, not after.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input! Regarding my issue with Isotope loading at the bottom of the page, which likely causes the "Isotope is not defined" error, how can I ensure that Isotope is loaded before I attempt to use it in my custom JavaScript code? Should I adjust the enqueue order or modify my script's location in some way?

Comment: Well, I mentioned that that 5th argument being `true` is causing it to load at the footer of the page. Try removing that argument to start with and see where it loads and if it solves the problem. If it's still a problem even after removing that, then some more adjustments might need to be made.

Comment: no sir..it encountered the same error.

Comment: So you need to look at the html being generated and see if the script is being loaded before the other script that uses it. Feel free to paste the relevant snippets of html into a jsfiddle or pastebin or something.

Comment: Another interesting avenue is the use the $deps array, and register 'isotope' as a dependency for your 'main.js' script.

Comment: I rearranged the code but it encountered two new [errors](https://imgur.com/8UVB8lX). [Here](https://replit.com/@SarowerJahan/NotedUtilizedProcessor#functions.php) is my full  functions.php and HTML code that i use

Comment: It's possible that this is returning `null` : `var gridElement = document.querySelector('#trade-list');` . Try to find out if that's the case. I can't help you with the second error, not enough information to assist.

Comment: In all likelihood, `gridElement` is null because your script is running before the html gets loaded. If that's the case, you have 2 options. 1. put the `main.js` file in the foot instead of the head. 2. Run the code in some sort of `document.onLoad` callback, so that it runs only after the rest of the html has loaded.

Comment: in the previous comment, I shared the functions.php and HTML code.[here](https://replit.com/@SarowerJahan/LightgrayDarkgreyPrinter#index.js) my main.js file...

Comment: You're going to have to try what I said in my last comment. I believe `gridElement` is null for the reasons stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all about the order your files are loading / running in. You have to make sure your 'isotope' file is loading before your 'main' file, and you have to make sure your 'main' file is loaded in after the html because you do a querySelector in your main script.